# Mac Command Line Tool Swift Unit Tests

Tags: swift, xcode

I want to unit test a command line tool.
I go through the following progress

Create a new project using the macOS > Command Line Tool template. Call it "MyProject"

```swift
import Foundation

class MyCode {
    func hello() {
        print("hello")
    }
}

let code = MyCode()
code.hello()
```

Choose File > New > Target.
Select the macOS Unit Testing Bundle template. Call it "MyTests"

```swift
import XCTest
@testable import MyProject

class MyTests: XCTestCase {

    func testCode() {
        let sol = MyCode()
        sol.hello()
    }

}
```

Switch to test target.

Build failed.

How can I test this?

Comment: Is the target name for your command line tool `MyProject` or `MyCode`?  I see that `MyCode` is a `class` in your tool, but what is the name of the target name for the tool?  That's the one you want to import.

Comment: Typo, it's MyProject - it wouldn't build as MyCode

Comment: The build still fails when you `import MyProject` or is a different problem?  And if it is failing what is the exact error Xcode reports?

Comment: It always imported `MyProject`, there was a typo in the question.



Undefined symbol: MyProjectMyCode.__allocating_init() -> MyProject.MyCode
Undefined symbol: type metadata accessor for MyProject.MyCode

Comment: OK, so that's a linker error.  And it jogged my memory of what I did with unit testing a command line app when I last did it.  The problem I think is that command line tools don't have a bundle, and can't be the host application for the Unit Test bundle.  There are two solutions.  One is to add each file you want to test to your test target with File Inspector (the thing that slides in from the right).  In that case, you don't import anything except `XCTest`, because the sources are directly included in the test bundle.  Another way would be to make another target that can support the tests.

Comment: Yeah, I previously added files to the test target and it felt bad. Not sure making a new target is brilliant either, but at least good to know other people have similar issues.

Comment: I don't like the solutions either, but they're not as bad as providing for unit testing in a Swift package for Linux.  For that you have to manually (or use meta programming) add each and every test method to an `allTests` property in each `XCTestCase` subclass, and manually ensure that each of those subclasses is registered in `XCTestManifests.swift` because apparently on Linux Swift doesn't include the Obj-C runtime that XCTest normally depends on to automatically find the tests.